# Using a hyperlink within a next arrow in PowerApps

Tags: hyperlink, powerapps

I am trying to use a hyperlink within an nextArrow object in PowerApps.
The intended outcome is that when a user clicks the arrow the user will be directed to an external web page.

Any help of insight into this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OnSelect** Action:

```
Launch("www.stackoverflow.com")
```